# Pandas, Generating a table from DataFrame with mutliple columns merged into the new index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
      Sex        CC1         CC2          CC3          CC4         count
1     Male       GBM       cough       fever      poor feeding       1
2   Female       abd dist    GBM          DIB           AMS          1
3   Female       fever     convulsion     LOC           NaN          1
4     Male       fever      vomiting   convulsion       NaN          1
5   Female       cough       GBM          NaN           NaN          1
6   Female        AMS        NaN          NaN           NaN          1
```

I need the following results:

```
New-index        Female   Male  Total  
AMS              14.0   14.0   28.0
Abd pain          1.0    0.0    1.0
Headache          0.0    1.0    1.0
DIB              12.0   23.0   35.0
FOC               0      1.0    1.0
```

In the results data frame the 'New-index' column is a combination of `CC1', 'CC2', 'CC3' and 'CC4'. How can I achieve this in pandas?

Comment: Can you add sample dataframe `df` (with other columns 'CC1', 'CC2', CC3', 'CC4' ) to question, which produce `table` by `pivot_table`?

Comment: @jezrael, added a sample data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use first [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) and then [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Sex','count'], value_name='New-index')
print df1
       Sex  count variable     New-index
0     Male      1      CC1           GBM
1   Female      1      CC1      abd dist
2   Female      1      CC1         fever
3     Male      1      CC1         fever
4   Female      1      CC1         cough
5   Female      1      CC1           AMS
6     Male      1      CC2         cough
7   Female      1      CC2           GBM
8   Female      1      CC2    convulsion
9     Male      1      CC2      vomiting
10  Female      1      CC2           GBM
11  Female      1      CC2           NaN
12    Male      1      CC3         fever
13  Female      1      CC3           DIB
14  Female      1      CC3           LOC
15    Male      1      CC3    convulsion
16  Female      1      CC3           NaN
17  Female      1      CC3           NaN
18    Male      1      CC4  poor feeding
19  Female      1      CC4           AMS
20  Female      1      CC4           NaN
21    Male      1      CC4           NaN
22  Female      1      CC4           NaN
23  Female      1      CC4           NaN
```

```
print df1.pivot_table('count', 
                      index=['New-index'], 
                      columns=['Sex'],  
                      aggfunc='sum', 
                      margins=True, 
                      margins_name='Total')

Sex           Female  Male  Total
New-index                        
AMS              2.0   NaN    2.0
DIB              1.0   NaN    1.0
GBM              2.0   1.0    3.0
LOC              1.0   NaN    1.0
abd dist         1.0   NaN    1.0
convulsion       1.0   1.0    2.0
cough            1.0   1.0    2.0
fever            1.0   2.0    3.0
poor feeding     NaN   1.0    1.0
vomiting         NaN   1.0    1.0
Total           16.0   8.0   24.0
```

Comment: the new table should have just one index column that is composed with all the items in CC1, CC2, CC3, and CC4, and the sum of the tallies should then appear on Female and Male columns accordingly.

Comment: Can you add desired ouput.? Sorry, I understand it uncorrectly.

Comment: Sorry Amani, I still dont understand. You need under column `CC1` column `CC2`, then `CC3`, ...? But I understand doing desired output is harder as explain it. Maybe someone it understand better and get answer.

Comment: I think I understand it better. But output from input data are different? e.g - `AMS              2.0   0.0   2.0`

Comment: Yes, you are right they are different, I just formulated the data to have a picture of what I need. I did not include the whole original data frame or the whole result data frame. Just samples.